# How to improve the use of .nextAll(), .last() and .after()?

Tags: jquery, html

Is there a way to improve the following code? I suspect that it can be done without having to use the `.each()`, but am not sure how to accomplish this.

**JS:**

```
$('dt.something').each(function () {
    $(this).nextUntil('dt.something')
        .last()
        .after($('<dd>new one</dd>'))
});
```

The code above acts on the sample below to add a new `<dd>` after the indicated elements. Basically a new `<dd>` at the end of each "set" of `<dd>s` after each `<dt class="something">`:

```
<dl>
    <dt class="something">term 1</dt>
    <dd>definition 1-a</dd>
    <dd>definition 1-b</dd>
    <dd>definition 1-c</dd>
    <dd>definition 1-d</dd> <<-----here
    <dt class="something">term 2</dt>
    <dd>definition 2-a</dd>
    <dd>definition 2-b</dd>
    <dd>definition 2-c</dd> <<-----here
    <dt class="something">term 3</dt>
    <dd>definition 3-a</dd>
    <dd>definition 3-b</dd> <<-----here
</dl>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something along these lines

```
/* Select all dt.something elements inside dl that are immedialy after dd and add new element before it. */
$('dl dd + dt.something').before('<dd>new one</dd>'); 
/* Select last dd inside dl and add new elem after that */
$('dl dd:last').after('<dd>new one</dd>');
```

Comment: This works, but is not really what I'm looking for. I'm thinking more along the lines of a one-line solution. Thanks for trying.